# Lifecycle observer inconsistent with lifecycle functions on Nexus 5

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-lifecycle

I have noticed some inconsistent behavior on Nexus 5 devices between the standard Android lifecycle methods (`onCreate`, `onStart`, etc.) and a [LifecycleObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleObserver.html) attached to the [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) lifecycle.

The issue appears when opening a share dialog and then closing it again.

Given this activity:

```
package gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo

import android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle.Event.*
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver
import android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.util.Log
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    init {
        lifecycle.addObserver(object : LifecycleObserver {
            @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_CREATE)
            fun logOnCreate() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Observed: $ON_CREATE")
            }

            @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
            fun logOnStart() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Observed: $ON_START")
            }

            @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_RESUME)
            fun logOnResume() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Observed: $ON_RESUME")
            }

            @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_PAUSE)
            fun logOnPause() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Observed: $ON_PAUSE")
            }

            @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_STOP)
            fun logOnStop() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Observed: $ON_STOP")
            }

            @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_DESTROY)
            fun logOnDestroy() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Observed: $ON_DESTROY")
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.i(TAG, "Ran onCreate")
        email_button.setOnClickListener { openShareDialog() }
    }

    private fun openShareDialog() {
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).run {
            type = "message/rfc822"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("test@mail.com"))
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject")
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text")
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(this, "Send Email"))
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Log.i(TAG, "Ran onStart")
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.i(TAG, "Ran onResume")
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.i(TAG, "Ran onPause")
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        Log.i(TAG, "Ran onStop")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.i(TAG, "Ran onDestroy")
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
    }
}
```

I expect every lifecycle transition to be logged both from the observer and the corresponding lifecycle method.

However, when I click the button to open the share dialog and then dismiss  it again, the behavior is different for different devices.

The **Samsung Galaxy A3** behaves as I would expect:

```
04-03 12:53:55.394 30109-30109/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Ran onCreate
04-03 12:53:55.396 30109-30109/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Observed: ON_CREATE
04-03 12:53:55.398 30109-30109/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Ran onStart
04-03 12:53:55.398 30109-30109/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Observed: ON_START
04-03 12:53:55.404 30109-30109/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Ran onResume
04-03 12:53:55.404 30109-30109/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Observed: ON_RESUME

* Opened share menu *

04-03 12:54:02.431 30109-30109/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Observed: ON_PAUSE
04-03 12:54:02.432 30109-30109/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Ran onPause

* Closed share menu *

04-03 12:54:07.635 30109-30109/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Ran onResume
04-03 12:54:07.636 30109-30109/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Observed: ON_RESUME
```

The **Google Nexus 5** observes `ON_STOP` and `ON_START` even though `onStop` and `onStart` are never called:

```
04-03 12:51:32.964 22062-22062/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Ran onCreate
04-03 12:51:32.965 22062-22062/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Observed: ON_CREATE
04-03 12:51:32.977 22062-22062/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Ran onStart
04-03 12:51:32.977 22062-22062/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Observed: ON_START
04-03 12:51:32.977 22062-22062/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Ran onResume
04-03 12:51:32.977 22062-22062/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Observed: ON_RESUME

* Opened share menu *

04-03 12:51:42.676 22062-22062/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Observed: ON_PAUSE
04-03 12:51:42.676 22062-22062/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Ran onPause
04-03 12:51:43.395 22062-22062/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Observed: ON_STOP

* Closed share menu *

04-03 12:51:47.791 22062-22062/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Ran onResume
04-03 12:51:47.791 22062-22062/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Observed: ON_START
04-03 12:51:47.791 22062-22062/gustavkarlsson.se.lifecycleerrordemo I/MainActivity: Observed: ON_RESUME
```

My question is: Why does the Nexus observe events even though the corresponding lifecycle method is never run? Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding the lifecycle?

Versions:

- `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0`
- `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.31`
- `com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0`
- `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0`
- `compileSdkVersion 27`
- `targetSdkVersion 27`

I've uploaded the demo project [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07538981190290130516).

Comment: Google Nexus 5 open share dialog full screen? is Activity visible partially or not ?

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel The share dialog is full-screen but semi-transparent, so you can see the activity through it.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy A3 share dialog is not  full screen right ?

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel Right. It's not, but what difference should that make?

Comment: then you have to re-learn life cycle of `activity`. when activity goes in `onpause` state and when `OnStop`.

Comment: This issue is not about the lifecycle itself, but about the inconsistency between lifecycle methods and lifecycle observers. Why is the ON_STOP event observed, but onStop is not called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lifecycle library marks `AppCompatActivity` and `Fragment` Lifecycle objects as `CREATED` and dispatches `ON_STOP` when `onSaveInstanceState()` is called without waiting for a call to the `onStop()` method. This is [described in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#onStop-and-savedState) for the library.

The documentation states this was done to make it easier for observers not to do things that would alter the UI state after `onSaveInstanceState()` has been called, because such changes would not be saved if the Activity or Fragment was stopped and destroyed straight after.

Your code didn't have any logging in `onSaveInstanceState()`, which is why you didn't see this method call logged.

NB. I'm assuming that you're using version 1.0.0-rc2 or higher of the Lifecycle library, which was released October 18, 2017 (several months before your question). According to the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes#release_candidate_-_october_18_2017), this behavior changed in that release.